# How to communicate with r data from power bi with parameterized filter

Tags: r, powerbi, r-forestplot

I am working to create a chart (Forest Plot Chart) using power bi, but there is no such kind of chart is found. In R, there is a possibility to create Forest Plot Chart i have found on few links over internet.

Now i need to know, is it possible to use that chart created in r data model could be imported in Power BI to visualize with parameters to apply filers on the r data model.

Thanks in advance.